# Pass encrypted email in url in nop commerece

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to **pass encrypted email in url**,but its not working on server,
while it is working on localhost.

I check the encrypted email- It contains some specific character like + , =
all those url which contains + sign are not working on server. but it working on localhost.

for example-
url format - {controllername}/{methodname}/{encrypted email}/{bool}

working url- 
[www.test.com/home/index/IZoc1QJlukTro7XN4kTaRDoy7mPNS-14YjKeZsXeyt3XsL4tXbLUPQ==/false](http://www.test.com/home/index/IZoc1QJlukTro7XN4kTaRDoy7mPNS-14YjKeZsXeyt3XsL4tXbLUPQ==/false)

not working url-
[www.test.com/home/index/KV6UWqy5fN7FY+lZuMAQ5nvA0+X4f8sQyB0la+-bSawUPEY1TIHK-C2bUdZUBRA6/false](http://www.example.com/home/index/KV6UWqy5fN7FY+lZuMAQ5nvA0+X4f8sQyB0la+-bSawUPEY1TIHK-C2bUdZUBRA6/false)

not working url gives error like
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass it as an url encoded query string parameter and not as part of the route:

```
http://www.test.com/home/index?email=IZoc1QJlukTro7XN4kTaRDoy7mPNS-14YjKeZsXeyt3XsL4tXbLUPQ%3D%3D%2Ffalse
```

If you want to pass some string as part of the route you should ensure that it doesn't contain dangerous characters which is your case. Scott Hanselman wrote a nice and detailed blog post on the difficulties that you might encounter if you attempt to pass such strings as part of the route here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx

I will quote his conclusion if you don't want to go through the entire post:

> After ALL this effort to get crazy stuff in the Request Path, it's
>   worth mentioning that simply keeping the values as a part of the Query
>   String (remember WAY back at the beginning of this post?) is easier,
>   cleaner, more flexible, and more secure.

Comment: it also not work when i pass email parameter in query string like http://www.exampe.com/home/index?email=ACnbE4oDoHhzeuaTbjHLVDCmFB+SQt3ax5xWCnBRIftFkYs8kv1c0o8k1UvcJQx7&active=True

Comment: @Darin but what if there is no other way than to pass this as a route values, There is no solution to this? if I can replace '+' with any other character

Comment: @NitinVarpe : It will be great if you provide more details about your comment in the form of an answer. This may definitely help others.